# Matplotlib animation patch initialization and rotation. How to do it right?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

What are the right ways to initialize and rotate patches in animations?  The attached program initializes and rotates patches in an animation, but my solutions are kind of a kludge.

To keep the initialized patches from showing up as static patches, I set alpha=0, but this means that I have to set alpha=1 every time I call the animate function, when I should only have to set this once.  I could put in an "if i==0;" statement before the set_alpha(1) call, but that seems inelegant.

To rotate the patches, I use "mag1._angle = i" (see lines 37 & 39) which uses Rectangle's internal attribute _angle.  You're not really supposed to do this but I don't see an alternative easy solution.  What do the Pythonistas say?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1, 1), ylim=(-1, 1), aspect=1)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

r_in, r_out = 0.25, 0.35
circ_outer = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_out, ec='blue', fc='white', lw=3)
circ_inner = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_in, ec='blue', fc='white', lw=3)
ax.add_patch(circ_outer)
ax.add_patch(circ_inner)

r, w, h = 0.5, 0.07, 0.4
x0, y0 = r, 0.5*h
mag1 = plt.Rectangle((-x0,-y0), width= w, height= h, angle=0, fc='black', alpha=0)
mag2 = plt.Rectangle(( x0, y0), width=-w, height=-h, angle=0, fc='black', alpha=0)
line1, = ax.plot([], [], 'b', zorder=1)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], 'b', zorder=1)

def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    ax.add_patch(mag1)
    ax.add_patch(mag2)
    return mag1, mag2, line1, line2,

def animate(i):
    mag1.set_alpha(1)
    mag2.set_alpha(1)
    thetaMAG = np.radians(i)
    x = x0*np.cos(thetaMAG) - y0*np.sin(thetaMAG)
    y = x0*np.sin(thetaMAG) + y0*np.cos(thetaMAG)
    mag1.xy = (-x, -y)
    mag1._angle = i
    mag2.xy = (x, y)
    mag2._angle = i
    j = float(i)/3.0
    thetaROT = np.radians(j)
    sn = r_in*np.sin(thetaROT)
    cs = r_in*np.cos(thetaROT)
    line1.set_data([-cs, cs], [-sn, sn])
    line2.set_data([sn, -sn], [-cs, cs])
    return mag1, mag2, line1, line2,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1080, 
                               interval=25, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: artists have a `visible` attribute (set via `set_visible` iirc) which might be helpful here.